# CherryPy Session Authentication?

Tags: session, authentication, cherrypy

I'm able to set session var's & get them too. BUT, the documentation for [cherrypy.lib.cptools.SessionAuth](http://docs.cherrypy.org/stable/refman/lib/cptools.html#cherrypy.lib.cptools.SessionAuth) is too *cryptic* for me to get anything out of it. I tried some things in code, but it either resulted in errors or blank pages. The tutorial on the site doesn't get into session auth. I did find an [old tutorial about making a blog in CherryPy 2.x](http://www.cherrypy.org/chrome/common/2.2/docs/book/chunk/ch03.html), but that seems a bit outdated to work with CherryPy 3.2.2. Can anyone point me to a real tutorial for this or give a code example so I can see how to make it work? I really don't know where else to look or ask, and this is gettin' frustrating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use this version of authentication.  Works well for me...

https://github.com/cherrypy/tools/blob/master/AuthenticationAndAccessRestrictions

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! This is a lot clearer on exactly how to do sessions & authentication... You rawwk dude.